# CSOM API for installing /Upgrading SharePoint Hosted app from sharePoint Store/ App Catalog?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

Is there any CSOM/JSOM  API available for installing /Upgrading Sharepoint Hosted App from sharePoint Store/ App Catalog?

Comment: I have a client with several hundred sites and subsites where SharePoint Add-Ins are installed. It is painful upgrading add-ins manually, to say the least. Any tips on automating this would be appreciated!